# Window.close script doesn't seem to close

Tags: html

Having trouble getting this code to actually close a window. Can anyone help? When the "return" is clicked it just goes to a blank page.

```
 <form method="post" action="http://ww8.aitsafe.com/cf/add.cfm" target="newWindow" onsubmit="window.open('', 'newWindow','width=800,height=500,'+'scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,top=200,left=200')">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="A8403475">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="window.close">
<input type="hidden" name="thumb" value="logo.png"> 
<select name="productpr">
<option>- Select Size -</option>
<option value="Size one:9.99">Size one - 9.99</option>
<option value="Size two:12.99">Size two - 12.99</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Defining your code as a value of hidden input field will do nothing** in this case.

Create a button and do something similar to this: `<button type="button" onclick="window.close();">Close</button>`

You didn't specify when you want the window to be closed...

Comment: That works, but I need it to be in the window that it opens. I don't have access to the code that the window opens as its hosted elsewhere. But I do have access to change the action of "return". For example, I can put in a URL and it goes there on click. But can't get it to close itself.

Comment: @Luke so try to put in as the value `window.close()`.

Comment: Did that and it goes to a blank page.

Comment: You did `window.close` or `window.close()`?

Comment: window.close(). Wait, is there supposed to be a space in between the brackets? :S

Comment: Do you see any space? No space.

Comment: Doesn't matter, did with a space and still goes to blank page